# Is there any library for subsetting OpenType PS (CFF) fonts?

Tags: fonts, subset, postscript, opentype

Is there any C/C++ library (preferably Open Source) for subsetting OpenType PS (CFF) fonts? [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/)
can be referred to, but I found [very negative comments](https://code.google.com/p/typochop/wiki/SubsettingOpenType) about its stability.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API includes a [**Font Embedding Services Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I believe performs subsetting as part of preparing fonts for embedding in documents. See in particular the [`CreateFontPackage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Windows API is callable from C/C++. Its implementation is not open source, of course.

The [**Adobe Font Development Kit for Opentype** (AFDKO)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_overview.html) has libraries that let you do a variety of things. Maybe it can do the kind of subsetting you are after. Its libraries are most commonly invoked from the Python language, but it's possible to build a C/C++ binding for Python libraries and vice versa. The AFDKO has an End-User License Agreement, which I understand to be proprietary but not onerous. You should judge for yourself.

I haven't used either of these APIs for the purpose of subsetting fonts, I just know them by reputation.

Comment: The Font Embedding Services Library is related to TT & OpenType(TT) fonts. Even the CreateFontPackage documentation says: "The CreateFontPackage function creates a subset version of a specified TrueType font ".
I had skimmed over the AFDKO, but didn't find references to subsetting. I'll check it again, maybe ttx is useful for CFF fonts too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you can not find one.

I have tried to find the lib that you want around the Internet, but failed. It seems that there is no open source lib to do this, although there are a dozen of lib which can subset TrueType font...

At last, I made it by myself. Because the code is owned to the company that I work for, I can not give you the code.

If you want to implement it, I think that it is helpful to read "The Compact Font Format Specification"("Adobe Technical Note #5176") and "The Type 2 Charstring Format"("Adobe Technical Note #5177"). And the MicroSoft's page https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm is helpful, too. The main thing to do is reading data from the CFF of a OpenType file and rewriting the data that you want to remain to a new file.

Good luck!